# Python Base64 - Decoding and Displaying an image

Tags: python, python-3.x, base64

I tried to decode the following base64 image

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,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
```

with:

```
import base64
x = """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""")
print(base64.b64decode(x))
```

also with using `encode("ascii")` for `x`:

```
import base64
x = """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""".encode("ascii")
print(base64.b64decode(x))
```

I saved the result as PNG image and JPG.
the issue here that the files didn't open, and I dont understand how the whole thing works. I watched some tutorials and I failed to display the image on my computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to write to the image file the binary of this string like this

```
f = open('img.png', 'wb')
f.write(base64.b64decode(x))
f.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do as follows:

```
import base64
image_64_decode = base64.decodestring(x) 
image_result = open('filename.png', 'wb') # create a writable image and write the decoding result
image_result.write(image_64_decode)
```

Comment: decodestring has been removed in late version. Thx for your help :)